# Where does malloc and global variable declaration allocates their variable to in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

In a simple C program, if I `malloc` a point that points to a variable or array, where is this part of memory allocated to in terms of memory map? I am very new to computer programming, so I am not sure how different variables are stored differently in the memory.

Also, where would a global variable (e.g. `int x = 5`) be stored to in the memory?

Lastly, is there any material that talks about how C language interacts with the low level hardware? What I found online are all related to C syntax, but I am too noob to read compiler books.

Please let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: Could you not Google any of this information. It's not hard to find ...

Comment: @AntonH I apologize for asking so-called basics, but I found way too much information than I need to understand this. Hope you understand.

Comment: +1: The question is a little vague, but it is interesting anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
int global_x = 5;
int global_y;

int main()
{
    int local_a;

    char* buf = malloc(100);
}
```

*While the following descriptions are not always the case (particularly in tiny embedded implementations), a typical program on a modern platform will be layed out as follows:*

- `global_x` is an initialized global variable. It is typically stored in a `.data` section in the executable file, and when the program is loaded, it lives in read-write, non-executable section of memory along side your program text.
- `global_y` is an uninitialized global variable. Space is reserved in the `.bss` section of the program, and takes up no space in the executable file. It lives in a simliar section as above when loaded.
- `local_a` is a local (or "automatic") variable that lives in the call **stack** of main. Its lifetime is constrained to the duration of execution in that function. (i.e. Once the function returns, the variable does not exist anymore, and is trashed.)
- `buf` points to a dynamically-allocated buffer of 100 bytes that is pulled from the [**heap**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_memory_allocation#DYNAMIC). The heap is an area of memory that usually will expand as needed to accomodate the memory requirements of the application. When heap space is exhausted (as determined by `malloc` and supporting library functions), additional memory will be requested from the operating system (e.g. `brk` or `mmap` on Linux).

---

On Linux, you can look at `/prod/[pid]/maps` to see the memory mapping for the process `[pid]`.  For example:

```
$ cat /proc/30009/maps
00400000-0040c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 268784                             /usr/bin/cat
0060b000-0060c000 r--p 0000b000 fd:01 268784                             /usr/bin/cat
0060c000-0060d000 rw-p 0000c000 fd:01 268784                             /usr/bin/cat
01a7a000-01a9b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
365ec00000-365ec20000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 263066                         /usr/lib64/ld-2.18.so
365ee1f000-365ee20000 r--p 0001f000 fd:01 263066                         /usr/lib64/ld-2.18.so
365ee20000-365ee21000 rw-p 00020000 fd:01 263066                         /usr/lib64/ld-2.18.so
365ee21000-365ee22000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
365f000000-365f1b4000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 263128                         /usr/lib64/libc-2.18.so
365f1b4000-365f3b4000 ---p 001b4000 fd:01 263128                         /usr/lib64/libc-2.18.so
365f3b4000-365f3b8000 r--p 001b4000 fd:01 263128                         /usr/lib64/libc-2.18.so
365f3b8000-365f3ba000 rw-p 001b8000 fd:01 263128                         /usr/lib64/libc-2.18.so
365f3ba000-365f3bf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f685162b000-7f6857b54000 r--p 00000000 fd:01 302750                     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f6857b54000-7f6857b57000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f6857b6c000-7f6857b6d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffa6f09000-7fffa6f2a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffa6ffe000-7fffa7000000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

We see that there are three parts of `/usr/bin/cat` mapped in at `0x400000`, `0x60b000`, and `0x60c000`.

By looking at the output of `readelf -a /usr/bin/cat` you can identify which sections correspond to the segments that are loaded at those addresses. This is left as an excercise to the reader :-)

Answer (score 0):

Global variables and static variables are in the *data segment*.

Memory allocated with `malloc()` is in the *heap*.

Automatic variables in functions are are in the *stack*.

Here's a web site that explains process memory layout: http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/

It's not specific to C, but it shows how these different memory areas are located in the process memory.

Comment: What's automatic variable?

Comment: Local variables in a function that aren't declared `static`.

Comment: While "data segment" is particularly vague (on-disk? in-memory?) `malloc` does not pull from a `.data` section, or even the same area of the memory map.

Answer (score -2):

All "malloc"-ed variables/arrays are allocated memory in the heap space, while all other variables are allocated memory in the stack.

You should be able to find a lot of tutorials online.

Comment: static and global variables are allocated in BSS and not on the stack nor heap.

Comment: Wrong. Only local variables are on the stack.